# Bootstrap css will not load even though it links to css min file

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a folder with index.html and a css folder that containers my bootstrap.min.css file and a js folder that contains my bootstrap.min.js and my jquery files and for some reason bootstrap will not load or work. If I use the bootstrap CDN for just the css the page works fine. I am not sure what the problem is with the min file. Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Comming Soon</title>
<link herf ="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel ="stylesheet" media="all">
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<div class="content-wrapper">
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "content"> 
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> <!-- always take up all the space -->

                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="panel-title">
                                <h2>Comming Soon!</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <center>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h1>Don't worry Marvin is building somthing cool</h1><br>
                            <small>come back soon, in the mean time here is some other of his stuff</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
hey guess so my source code does have the css/bootstrap.min.css etc etc but that was not the problem the problem was I needed to include css/bootstrap.css above that link, idk why but that fixed it. cheers

Comment: you have a typo in `href` -> `<link herf ="bootstrap.min.css" rel ="stylesheet" media="all">`

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/ would have identified that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelt `href` as `herf`, it should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following line  
    `<link herf ="bootstrap.min.css" rel ="stylesheet" media="all">`     
to  
    `<link href ="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">`

Answer (score -1):

If your bootstrap files is inside css folder,you should use

```
<link href ="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel ="stylesheet" media="all">
```

Answer (score -1):

As your css is the css folder you have to tell the browser the whole path, browser will not gonna pick it automatically. So define it as follows

```
<link herf ="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel ="stylesheet" media="all">
```